# What is the Despair kernal for Nexus 5 and 6?

Tags: rooting, nexus-5, kernel

I'm rooting my nexus 5 with android m and it asks me to install Despair Kernel. I can't find any info on what does the despair kernel actually do. Is it safe? What improvements does it have vs stock kernel? Also what are some other kernels aside from despair?